# Show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)-f(x-t)|dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)-f(x-t)|dx = 0$.

What I want to do is bound $|f(x)-f(x-t)|$ above by something and then use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem to move the limit inside the integral sign, which would solve the problem. I know that $f$ is finite for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, but I don't know that it's bounded, so I'm not sure if this is a feasible approach. In a previous question on this homework set I showed that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x+a)dx$, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$, but I'm not sure if that can be applied to this problem. Any hints will be appreciated (it is a homework problem, so I would prefer hints over a complete solution).

Comment: Is it clear that $f(x-t) \to f(x)$ as $t\to 0$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @John Yes. My problem with this, as with most of analysis is that while it "makes sense" I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: You can try to prove this for $g$ continuous with compact support. Then for the general $f$, use approximation by a continuous $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I assume you want to ask 
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\int|{f(x)-f(x-t)}|\,dx=0$$
but not
$$ \lim_{t\to \infty}\int|{f(x)-f(x-t)}|\,dx=0$$
You want $t\to0$ but not $t\to\infty$ right?

Next, from your previous hw, we know
$$ \int_{R^N} f(x)\,dx = \int_{R^N} f(x-t)\,dx$$

Also, I assume you know that the continuous function is dense in $L^1(R^N)$ and hence we can have a sequence of functions $(f_n)\subset C_c^0(R^N)$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

Now here is how LDCT comes in. We have $|f_n(x)-f_n(x-t)|\leq |f_n(x)|+|f_n(x-t)|$ by triangle inequality for a.e. $x\in R^N$.  Hence we could dominate $|f_n(x)-f_n(x-t)|$ by $|f_n(x)|+|f_n(x-t)|$. The later item is integrable because $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ and hence we have $\|f_n\|_{L^1}\leq \|f\|_{L^1}+1$ for $n$ large enough. Now, LDCT will tell you that you could move your limit from outside into inside and you have

$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\int|{f_n(x)-f_n(x-t)}|\,dx=0$$

To conclude, we write
$$ \int|{f(x)-f(x-t)}|\,dx\leq  \int|{f(x)-f_n(x)}|\,dx +\int|{f_n(x)-f_n(x-t)}|\,dx+ \int|{f(x-t)-f_n(x-t)}|\,dx $$

Notice that for any given $\epsilon>0$, you could choose $n$ large enough so that the first and last term is less then $\epsilon/3$. Next take $t$ small enough you have second term less the n$\epsilon/3$. Sum up, you have whole thing is less then $\epsilon$ and hence you could conclude your result.

The first and last item goes to $0$ because $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

If you don't know why $C_c^0$ is dense in $L^1$, actually $L^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$, I think you could find prove in Rudin's book.

The key is LDCT only require the dominate function to be integrable, but not finite nor bounded.

Comment: Yes, it is $t \to 0$, I fixed it in the question. Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Just to make sure: Is it sure that $f(x-t) \to f(x)$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb R^N$?

Comment: No it is not. You need to use something else. I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: Now the answer is complete

Comment: @wisher I'm not familiar with the notation $C_c^0$. What does it stand for?

Comment: $C_c^0(R^N)$ is defined as the collection of all compact supported continuous function in $R^N$.

Comment: @wisher Can I conclude that the middle term goes to zero once I have proved that the property holds for compactly supported functions?

Comment: Yes, this is why we use approximation.

Comment: @wisher I figured, I just wanted to make absolutely sure. Thank you again!

Comment: @spatially I don't understand why you have to introduce the $f_n$ in your prove, maybe you could explain it further. why do you have to make such a detour over the $f_n$, if you already know $\lim_{t\to 0}\int|{f_n(x)-f_n(x-t)}|\,dx=0$ why can't you just apply this to f, i.e. why do you have to use the $f_n$ in the first place?